# How to calculate 10^pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get a new series by calculating 10 to the power of an existing series. I have tried `pandas.Series.rpow` and `numpy.power`, but they all show strange results.
Here is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv', sep=',', header=None, encoding='utf-8')
iexp = data.iloc[:, 9]
s = pd.Series(10, index=iexp.index)
print(s ** iexp)
```

[image: Result of my code]

Comment: I guess `int64` is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BigBen suggested, `int64` is the problem here. You need to change it to a proper dtype:

```
df = df.astype("float")
```

Consider the following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10,20,30,34],
                   'B': [10,10,10,10]})
df
```

output:

[image]

The columns have `int64` dtypes:

```
df.dtypes
```

output:

[image]

Something similar to your code:

```
iexp = df.iloc[:, 0]
s = pd.Series(10, index=iexp.index)
iexp, s
```

output:

[image]

Now, the output of

```
print(s ** iexp)
```

is this:

[image]

As can be discerned, the `int64` dtypes becomes problematic at **too** large numbers.

Now, change the dtype:

```
df = df.astype("float")
```

Now, the dtypes are `float64` and you would get the following outputs:

[image]

[image]

Finally, note that you can change the dtype of a subset of columns as well if needed. For example to give the column A the dtype of `float`:

```
df = df.astype({"A": float})
```

Comment: Thank you for your amazing explanation. It really makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

```
data = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv', sep=',', header=None, encoding='utf-8')
iexp = data.iloc[:, 9]

def power_10(x):
    return 10 ** x

iexp.apply(power_10)
```

Comment: Yes this works by changing a little bit of your codes.
`iexp.apply(power_10)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly with:

```
10 ** iexp
```